# What is the significance of the dean making the soju bomb tissues stick to the wall?

Tags: barking-dogs-never-bite

In the movie *Barking Dogs Never Bite* (2000), the scenes depicting the dean drinking with Kung-min and Go Yoon-joo show the dean having an elaborate method to prepare the drinks. As I have gathered from [here](https://www.honestfoodtalks.com/soju-bomb-somaek-korean-drinking-games), the dean is probably employing the soju tornado technique in tandem with the technique to prepare soju bombs with tissue paper. However, what still remains a mystery to me is his throwing the tissues on the wall to make them stick to it thereafter. Is this a part of the Korean drinking traditions as well? Does the act of making the soju bomb tissues stick to the wall have any additional significance with respect to the movie?